# Call a value from State into componentDidMount () Function API URL

Tags: reactjs, jsx, es6-class

I am having issue with rendering a value from state in componentDidMount() Function API URL. Well I am basically making 2 API calls. The first call is getting the general data & and the second call is fetching the details of a specific record from the first call.

From the first call API response I am fetching the "uniquename" which is basically an ID and storing into state "Number" with the help of a function called "clickHandler". I am successfully getting the data from the state in render() method but I am not able to replace the ID in the second API call for details.

My requirement is when I click on the button, that specific uniquename replaces the id in the second call API URl for details of that specific record.

Here is My code.

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "./App.css";

class PenRecords extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      records: [],
      getdetails: [],
      errorMessage: "",
      errorMessage2: "",
      Number: "IR34400",
    };

    this.clickHandler = this.clickHandler.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const headers = {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      Authorization: "Bearer abcdef-fccf-9scegs-l6a7-844a4ff31296",
    };

    axios
      .get(
        "/api/approval/v1/prod/pendingRecords?realm=xyz-T&limit=5&offset=2",
        { headers }
      )
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState({ records: res.data });
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.setState({ errorMessage: error.message });
        console.log(error);
      });

    //Get Details - I am not able to access the State "Number" Value in this second call url"
    axios
      .get(
        "/api/approval/v1/prod/documentNumber/${this.state.Number}?realm=xyz",
        { headers }
      )
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState({ getdetails: res.data });
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.setState({ errorMessage2: error.message });
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  clickHandler(num) {
    this.setState({
      Number: num,
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { records } = this.state;
    const { getdetails } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.errorMessage && (
          <h3 className="error">{this.state.errorMessage}</h3>
        )}
        <ul className="ulSytle">
          {records.map((record, uniqueName) => (
            <li key={record.uniqueName}>
             - {record.uniqueName} 
             - {record.documentType}
             - {record.approver} -
             
              <button onClick={() => this.clickHandler(record.uniqueName)}>
                Get Details
              </button>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>

        <h1>Detials - This is the second API Call Response</h1>
        <h3>{this.state.errorMessage2}</h3>
        <h1> {this.state.Number} </h1> // I can render the value here set to state but can't in the Url.
        <ul>
          <li> Title : {getdetails.title} </li>
          <li> line Item Count : {getdetails.lineItemCount} </li>
          <li> Submit Date : {getdetails.submitDate} </li>
          <li> Site : {getdetails.site} </li>
          <li> Requester : {getdetails.requesterName}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default PenRecords;
```

Any Support is really Appreciated. Cheers !!

Comment: In terms of what you're looking for, when you click the button, do you want to just set the value of the `Number ` state variable or do you want to also make an API call to `/api/approval/v1/prod/documentNumber/`?

Comment: Hi @Tejogol Thanks for your reply. I have already set the value to state "Number"  via the function clickHandler. Infact I can view the value in the render section. My concern is to make the api call  "/api/approval/v1/prod/documentNumber/${this.state.Number}   and bring that value from state here.

Comment: You need to use backticks (`) not quotes (") around the url string with the state in it for interpolation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, you're looking to make an API call to `"/api/approval/v1/prod/documentNumber/${this.state.Number}?realm=xyz"` each time a user clicks the button that calls `clickHandler`. This can be achieved by moving the API call out of `componentDidMount` and doing away with  the `Number` state variable entirely by just passing the variable into the function.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "./App.css";

class PenRecords extends Component {
  headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    Authorization: "Bearer abcdef-fccf-9scegs-l6a7-844a4ff31296"
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      records: [],
      getdetails: [],
      errorMessage: "",
      errorMessage2: ""
    };

    this.clickHandler = this.clickHandler.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let url =
      "/api/approval/v1/prod/pendingRecords?realm=xyz-T&limit=5&offset=2";
    axios
      .get(url, this.headers)
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState({ records: res.data });
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.setState({ errorMessage: error.message });
        console.log(error);
       });
   }

   clickHandler(uniqueName) {
     let url =
       "/api/approval/v1/prod/documentNumber/" + uniqueName + "?realm=xyz";
     axios
       .get(url, this.headers)
       .then((res) => {
         this.setState({ getdetails: res.data });
         console.log(res);
       })
       .catch((error) => {
         this.setState({ errorMessage2: error.message });
         console.log(error);
       });
  }

   render() {
     const { records } = this.state;
     const { getdetails } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.errorMessage && (
          <h3 className="error">{this.state.errorMessage}</h3>
        )}
        <ul className="ulSytle">
           {records.map((record, uniqueName) => (
            <li key={record.uniqueName}>
              - {record.uniqueName}- {record.documentType}- {record.approver} 
              <button onClick={() => this.clickHandler(record.uniqueName)}>
                Get Details
              </button>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>

        <h1>Detials - This is the second API Call Response</h1>
        <h3>{this.state.errorMessage2}</h3>
        <ul>
          <li> Title : {getdetails.title} </li>
          <li> line Item Count : {getdetails.lineItemCount} </li>
          <li> Submit Date : {getdetails.submitDate} </li>
          <li> Site : {getdetails.site} </li>
          <li> Requester : {getdetails.requesterName}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default PenRecords;
```

Comment: I have no words to thank you. It really works. Thanks alot

Comment: Hi @Tejogol. I have just one question. The code is working now perfectly. When I click on the record button, it updates the details in the second call. Now I want to transfer the second call to a separate component. How can I do that Please?

Comment: @Raza Are you looking to display another component to the user when the button is clicked, or are you simply looking to move the second call to a new component?